# change order of vertices in multiple edge igraph

Tags: r, igraph, vertices

I've made a network with igraph, but I cannot change the order of verticies.

Here is the data:

```
network_data$from <- c("PT", "MF", "SM", "PT", "EC", "SM", "EC", "MF", "SM", "PT", "EC", "MF")

network_data$to <- c("EC", "EC", "EC", "MF", "MF", "MF", "PT", "PT", "PT", "SM", "SM", "SM")

network_data$estimate <- c(-0.4098754, -0.2024286, -0.4142742,  1.1567407,  0.0000000,  0.6768688,  1.9278870, 0.0000000,  0.8435933,  0.0000000,  0.8028104, -0.2927398)
```

And my code to create a multi-edged graph (i.e., more than one edge connecting two verticies), where the weights of the edges are determined by "estimate" in the data. It's important I keep the 'layout=layout.circle' argument because it should look like another network I've produced.

```
nodes <- as_tibble(unique(network_data$to)) %>% rename(nodes = value) %>% mutate(RA = c(0.826, 0.0229, 0.311, 0.431))
links <- network_data %>% filter(estimate != 0)

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=TRUE)

E(net)$color[E(net)$estimate > 0] <- "blue"
E(net)$color[E(net)$estimate < 0] <- "red"

net <- set.edge.attribute(net, "width", index = E(net),abs(E(net)$estimate)*5)

plot.igraph(net, layout=layout.circle, vertex.size = 30, vertex.label.cex = 1.5, vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved=.2, edge.arrow.size = 1.2, directed = TRUE, order = coords)
```

Interestingly, if I take away the `layout=layout.circle` argument, each time I run the command the order of the vertices will change. However, like I said before, I'd like to keep that layout of the network (i.e., 'layout=layout.circle') to aggree with other figures I've produced.

I'd be grateful for any advice. And if you have any other question as to how I can clean up the code, please let me know. I'm new to igraph and this object that is created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try some of the options below to influence the order of the vertices. First, I'll re-share the code to generate the data and so on, since I had to make a couple of small revisions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

network_data <- tibble(from = c("PT", "MF", "SM", "PT", "EC", "SM", "EC", "MF", 
                                "SM", "PT", "EC", "MF"),
                       to = c("EC", "EC", "EC", "MF", "MF", "MF", "PT", "PT", 
                              "PT", "SM", "SM", "SM"),
                       estimate = c(-0.4098754, -0.2024286, -0.4142742, 1.1567407, 
                                    0.0000000, 0.6768688, 1.9278870, 0.0000000,  
                                    0.8435933, 0.0000000, 0.8028104, -0.2927398))

nodes <- as_tibble(unique(network_data$to)) %>% 
  rename(nodes = value) %>% mutate(RA = c(0.826, 0.0229, 0.311, 0.431))
links <- network_data %>% filter(estimate != 0)

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=TRUE)

E(net)$color[E(net)$estimate > 0] <- "blue"
E(net)$color[E(net)$estimate < 0] <- "red"

net <- set.edge.attribute(net, "width", index = E(net),abs(E(net)$estimate)*5)
```

now, I tested two options to influence the order of vertices:

Option 1:

```
coords <- layout_in_circle(net, order = c(V(net)[1], V(net)[3], V(net)[2], V(net)[4]))
plot.igraph(net, layout=layout.circle, 
            vertex.size = 30, vertex.label.cex = 1.5, 
            vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved=.2, edge.arrow.size = 1.2, 
            directed = TRUE)
```

Option 2:

```
net <- permute(net, c(V(net)[1], V(net)[3], V(net)[2], V(net)[4]))
plot.igraph(net, layout=layout.circle, 
            vertex.size = 30, vertex.label.cex = 1.5, 
            vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved=.2, edge.arrow.size = 1.2, 
            directed = TRUE)
```

Option 1 generates the coordinates for displaying the vertices using the layout_in_circle function [reference](https://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_in_circle.html), here, nothing in your graph (net) is changed. Option 2 changes the vertex indices in the graph (see also [reference](https://igraph.org/r/doc/permute.html))

I am not sure this is what you need but maybe it helps.